# Read Replica configuration in drupal

Tags: drupal, amazon-rds

I have hosted my drupal site on amazon and wanted to scale the dbserver to handle the increased traffic. I have enabled Read Replica of dbinstance of RDS. I dont know what all changes have to be done from drupal end to get this working.

If anyone has configured the above implementation into their site then some pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since Drupal 7, they made it very easy to use it with MySQL master(Read/Write)-slave(Read-only) setup. Assume that we have 2 MySQL servers configured in master-slave mode.

In settings.php, start with the MySQL master configuration.

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'mysql-master-db',
  'username' => 'mysql-master-username',
  'password' => 'mysql-master-password',
  'host' => 'mysql-master(Read + Write)-IP',
);
```

Now below this, add the following code to configure the slaves.

```
$databases['default']['slave'][] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'mysql-slave1-db',
  'username' => 'mysql-slave1-user',
  'password' => 'mysql-slave1-password',
  'host' => 'mysql-slave1(Read-only)-IP',
);
```

Now below this, if you want any of the select queries to use the slave server, then use the following syntax:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n', array('target' => 'slave'));
```

By providing array('target' => 'slave') argument, the query will run against one of the slave databases. If there are multiple such queries for the same page, then all will run on the same slave server. If no slave is available, then that option will be ignored and the query will run against the master.